# Unable to open InfoPath forms in web browser

Tags: iis, webserver, ms-office, infopath

I have created some InfoPath forms. I am using MS-Office 2010. I deployed these forms on IIS server. When I open the URL in my browser, a list of files gets opened. When I click on any of the form from list, it gives 3 options. One of them to open form in infopath. One says to save it etc

I want when I click on the form, it gets opened in the browser.
Please guide me how to achieve this purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you deployed the form to a SharePoint library? You don'y typically deploy to IIS directly.

Comment: You should publish the InfoPath form to SharePoint. In the file menu, choose Publish | Publish form to a SharePoint Library and follow the wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are publishing the infopath you can find Enable browser enabled form....
Other wise publish the form as content type..
Publish in your local machine and upload in central admin->General settings->Infopath forms upload->Activate to site collection  and in the site check your content type enabled.